# Google API Key + Access Token for Cloud Natural Language API

Tags: api, google-api, nlp, google-cloud-platform, access-token

I need a Google API Key and a Google Access Token to add to some sample code. However, when I create credentials for a Google Cloud NLP project, I get a JSON file that contains the code posted below. Which on is the API Key and which one is the access token? I'm so confused, thanks!

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-id",
  "private_key_id": "some_number",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....
  =\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "<api-name>api@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/...<api-name>api%40project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the Private Key in order to make a signed JWT (JSON Web Token). You then use this to request a new token. After you get the token from Google, you use that for subsequent requests by adding the token to your HTTP header:

```
Header Name  | value
-----------------------------
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

See [these Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) for all the details.